# C++ sizeof custom class returning incorrect value?

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn’t sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Given the following class, with no other data members:

```
typedef uint32_t id_t;
typedef int64_t loc_t;

class foo:
{
public:
    enum bar : uint8_t
    {
        BAR1,
        BAR2,
        BAR3
    };
private:
    id_t id;
    loc_t  start;
    loc_t  stop;
    bar std;
};
```

Can anyone explain why:

> sizeof( id_t ) returns 4...
>   sizeof( loc_t ) returns 8...
>   sizeof( bar ) returns 1...
>
> 4+(2*8)+1 = 21

Yet:

> sizeof( foo ) returns 32?

Removing the uint8_t requirement on the bar enum type only succeeds in making sizeof( bar ) return 4 (int)  while sizeof( foo ) still returns 32 when 24 would be properly byte aligned.

EDIT: The why has been satisfactorily answered. I thank everyone who commented as each brought a different set of detail to the table.

The fix I need is for being able to use sizeof() to create file location offsets. So that when I write a foo to a file in binary format I can find the location immediately following it if I am later given it's location.  I'll update here if I find an elegant solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're already aware if the concept of alignment. What part of the alignment calculation are you not understanding?

Comment: I just did not think of the expansion to 8 byte alignment... my thoughts were that 24 bytes (in the case that a bar is actually stored internally as an "int") would be aligned.  Below bames53 has explicitly shown me the errors of my judgment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is probably 8 byte aligned due to the `int64_t`s, so

```
sizeof(id_t) + 4 bytes padding + 2*sizeof(loc_t) + `sizeof(uint8_t)` + padding up to the next multiple of 8 =
4 + 4 bytes of padding + 16 + 1 + (padding up to the next multiple of 8) =
25 + padding to multiple of 8 =
32
```

Some compilers have a warning for padding (clang has -Wpadded):

```
warning: padding class 'foo' with 4 bytes to align 'start' [-Wpadded]
    loc_t  start;
           ^
warning: padding size of 'foo' with 7 bytes to alignment boundary [-Wpadded]
class foo
      ^
```

You may also be able to control this using compiler extensions such as `#pragma pack(1)`

```
#pragma pack(1)
class foo:
{
public:
```

Of course there's a performance penalty for this, but this way  `sizeof(foo)` comes out as 21 for me on this system.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of byte alignment very incorrectly.  Thank you and Sarang for straightening me out.  I was thinking that the padding would be less substantial and be more inclined toward 2 or four byte alignment.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of memory alignment.
Processor fetches data depending upon width of bus, 32-bit OS will align data on 4 byte boundary and 64-bit OS on 8-byte boundary.
Non-Aligned memory requires two memory-reads and leads to degraded performance.

Read all about memory alignment here:

1. http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13265
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx

Comment: I ninja edited you sorry.  I understand that it will try for some sort  of byte alignment.  But in the case where the enum takes a full 4 byte integer the total size should be 24 right? And 24 would yield appropriate byte alignment would it not?

Comment: @user1445306, the alignment is compiler-dependent and architecture-dependent. The total size may be 24, 32, or even 64 or other, if compiler decides that it's best for performance.

Comment: I think I'll have to look and see what all of the values are for my cross compilation tools (embedded Linux for ARM built on x86_64 Linux)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to padding. The compiler may leave "spaces" in your struct, to ensure the variables inside the struct are well-aligned, for more efficient access.

You may override the default struct member alignment (at least in MSVC, by specifying `#pragma pack`.

Comment: Got the answer for GCC?  I tried things like __attribute__((packed)) and ((align...